# Problem with security settings in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, sdk, azure

I’ve run into a problem while upgrading Azure SDK from version 1.2 to 1.3. After upgrading the development environment no longer allows me to make security-changes in web.config. More specifically the web role fails when I add this setting:

```
<system.webServer>
 <security>
  <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
 </security>
</system.webServer>
```

It outputs the following error message:

> "This configuration section cannot be
>   used at this path. This happens when
>   the section is locked at a parent
>   level. Locking is either by default
>   (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set
>   explicitly by a location tag with
>   overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy
>   allowOverride="false"."

I’ve tried changing ApplicationHost.config in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config and C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config (i.e. changing the overrideModeDefault from Deny to Allow for the Security-section) but that didn’t do the trick. Does anyone know what changes must be made in order to allow me to change these settings in web.config in the Azure development environment?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions from this post?  http://forums.asp.net/p/1220987/2178061.aspx

Comment: Give everybody full rights on the folder containing webfiles might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change from Deny to Allow in just one place? In needs to be done in two places.

Change all of the following values located in section  -->

```
<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

change this value from "Deny" to "Allow"

```
<section name="modules" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

change this value from "Deny" to "Allow"

Comment: Thanks but I solved it differently: I switched to Amazon AWS :).